# Insert multiple object to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there an other way to insert multiple objects to an MySQL database than the way shown here. This works but takes time to execute.

```
  using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            //Goes thrue the List<object>
            foreach(List<object> sub in listSubject)
            {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "CALL stp_InsertSubject(@param_SubjectId, @param_ProjectId, @param_Used);";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_SubjectId",Convert.ToInt32(sub[0]) );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_ProjectId", Convert.ToInt32(sub[1]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_Used", Convert.ToBoolean(sub[2]) );

            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
                }
```

My Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mortenstarck`@`%` PROCEDURE `stp_InsertSubject`(param_SubjectId int(45), param_ProjectId int(45), param_Used tinyint(1))
```

BEGIN
INSERT INTO `Subject_has_Projects`(`Subject_Id`, `Projects_Id`, `Used`) VALUES (param_SubjectId, param_ProjectId, param_Used);
END

Comment: You would need to show us what `stp_InsertSubject` does exactly to answer that...

Comment: Your `Id = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` getting override every time in loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to improve:

- Open the connection just one time outside the loop (no need to close
  with using)
- Create the command, assign connection just one time before the loop
- Create the parameters all before the loop with dummy values
- Assign only the value inside the loop and call the ExecuteScalar()

`using(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStr))
{  
    conn.Open(); 
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();   
    cmd.Connection = conn;   
    cmd.CommandText = "CALL stp_InsertSubject(@param_SubjectId, @param_ProjectId, @param_Used);";  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_SubjectId",0 );   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_ProjectId", 0);   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_Used", false );   
    foreach(List<object> sub in listSubject)   
    {   
        cmd.Parameters["@param_SubjectId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(sub[0]) ;   
        cmd.Parameters["@param_ProjectId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(sub[1]);   
        cmd.Parameters["@param_Used"].Value = Convert.ToBoolean(sub[2]);   
        Id = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();   
    }   
}`

Comment: Why would you use dummy values. Why not just create the parameters with explicit types?

Comment: @ConradFrix I'm trying to put up an example but can't format the code right

Answer (score 1):

You can try. Open connection outside `foreach` loop. This will save time in opening and closing connection every time in loop. This will improve performance.

```
Int64 Id = 0;
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    //Goes through the List<object>
    conn.Open();
    foreach(List<object> sub in listSubject)
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "CALL stp_InsertSubject(@param_SubjectId, @param_ProjectId, @param_Used);";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_SubjectId",Convert.ToInt32(sub[0]) );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_ProjectId", Convert.ToInt32(sub[1]));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_Used", Convert.ToBoolean(sub[2]) );
        Id = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
     conn.Close();
}
```

[How bad is opening and closing a SQL connection for several times? What is the exact effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404261/how-bad-is-opening-and-closing-a-sql-connection-for-several-times-what-is-the-e)

Comment: Curse my slow fingers! This is probably the best way to solve your problem without changing your method of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about surrounding these calls with a single transaction?