# vb.net save in phpmyadmin null values return

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

I am new in vb.net, sql and even record data in phpmyadmin. When I add the records using my interface, I checked my phpmyadmin and it was indicating to have an entry in the table meaning my vb.net and phpmyadmin is connected but the values returned NULL. How can I make it not NULL? instead ,records the desired data?

This is my code:

```
Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost; database=patientinfo;user id=root;password=" 
Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection()

Public Sub SaveInfos(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()

    End With
    SQLConnection.Close()

    'MsgBox("Successfully Added!")
    MsgBox("Successfully Saved")
    Me.Visible = False
    Mainform.Show()

    SQLConnection.Dispose()
End Sub

 Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    Try
        '===========================Add New Patient========================================
        bednumber = txtbednum.Text
        patient_name = txtName.Text
        patient_age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text)
        date_of_confinement = Date.Parse(dtpDate.Value)
        type_of_sickness = txtSickness.Text
        type_of_IV_fluid = txtFluid.Text
        number_of_bottles = Convert.ToInt32(txtBottle.Text)
        drop_rate = Convert.ToInt32(txtDrop.Text)

        'To check if all values have been filled up
        If patient_name = "" Or patient_age = "" Or date_of_confinement = "" _
        Or type_of_sickness = "" Or type_of_IV_fluid = "" Or number_of_bottles = "" Or drop_rate = "" _
        Then

            MsgBox("Please Complete All the Required Fields")

        Else

            Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO patient(bednumber, name, age, date_of_confinement,type_of_sickness, type_of_IV_fluid, number_of_bottles, drop_rate) VALUES(@bednumber, @name, @age, @date_of_confinement, @type_of_sickness, @type_of_IV_fluid, @number_of_bottles, @drop_rate)"
            SaveInfos(SQLStatement)
```

This what my table looks like in phpmyadmin:

http://i1182.photobucket.com/albums/x454/catherinefbalauro/Untitled.png

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: ALREADY SOLVED BY ME :)) [CLOSED]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
' Assuming that your SQLStatement is as follow
' INSERT INTO MyTableName 
' VALUES (  @bednumber, @name, @age, 
'           @date_of_confinement,@type_of_sickness,
'           @type_of_IV_fluid, @number_Of_Bottles,
'           @drop_rate
'        )
With cmd
    .CommandText = SQLStatement
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .Connection = SQLConnection

    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@bednumber", txtbednum.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtAge.Text)
    ' dothe same until
    ' you have added allthe parameter
    ' with values

    SQLConnection.Open()
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

Comment: vb.net cannot accept .addwithvalue as it said that it is not member of MySqlParameterCollection o.o

Comment: no, is should have work..look at this code http://stackoverflow.com/a/10524452/491243

Comment: syntax of C# and vb is not the same right? when i try your suggestion it said is not member of mysqlparameter.
what my code accept is like this one:
.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@bednumber", txtbednum.Text))
but still NULL